# Notorious Git Error: remote rejected (failed to lock)

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push to a branch from my local to the origin. The branch name and the path is same. I have been pushing and pulling from this branch for a while and never had a problem. But suddenly, it started behaving badly. Last time when I tried to push to origin with following command:

```
git push origin feature/Prizefulfilment
```

It gives me following errror:

```
72c6c1da98e5cff4484e254a538d9e3b472156ff but expected 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have Googled around but did not find a quite satisfying solution to it yet.

My exact error looks like following:

```
$ git push origin feature/Prizefulfilment
Counting objects: 126, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Writing objects: 100% (78/78), 8.83 KiB, done.
Total 78 (delta 61), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: Ref refs/heads/feature/Prizefulfilment is at 72c6c1da98e5cff4484e254a538d9e3b472156ff but expected 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
remote: error: failed to lock refs/heads/feature/Prizefulfilment
To git@devtools.contestfactory.com:OpusOneSCRUM
 ! [remote rejected] feature/Prizefulfilment -> feature/Prizefulfilment (failed to lock)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@devtools.contestfactory.com:OpusOneSCRUM'`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to run `git fsck` on your local and remote to make sure nothing is seriously corrupted.

Comment: It returned some dangling commits on my local  `Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (106152/106152), done.
dangling blob 4118c6392bbea95a6404d40344e12ff8fe1e64c8
dangling blob a34f2078115375df3749567e01793e556f0e5ade
dangling blob 9a5e545d9056200834f74d6426144269974467a0
dangling blob 867c5821823a875e724203b5bc8bbf65c8b72931
dangling blob 128ccc6d40e4090cd725d37867308e525825b991
dangling blob 5b91603a188d5f13af4ef56b0f62d6d8caff92b4
dangling blob c6a5241f7a4c23a68456526adf94f3c784d1df69`
 and much more dangled

Comment: I followed with git prune and it removed a lot of dangling Blobs abut some dangling commits are still there...

Comment: I updated my question to include more details about the error.

Comment: Ok. new update. For some reason, `git push origin feature/PrizeFulfilment` was giving me error but when I did` git push feature/prizeFulfilment: feature/Prizefulfilment`, it worked... Don't know hows and whys of it. Just telling it explicitly what branch to look for just seems to work fine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
 git push feature/prizeFulfilment: feature/Prizefulfilment
```

That is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5169488/6309):

> For the record, I believe the root cause of this problem was the **difference in capitalisation between the local and remote branch names**, and the case-insensitive nature of the Windows share that hosted the remote repository.
>
> We just encountered this exact same error and were able to resolve the problem simply by renaming the local branch to match the capitalisation of the existing remote branch.

Try and make sure to **use the same capitalization between local and remote branches**.

You second command make the link between the `prizeFulfilment` and remote `Prizefulfilment` explicit, which is why it worked. But it isn't a good solution to keep a local branch with that kind of difference.

Comment: making sure the capitalization is the same solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

I saw this error happen because a previous branch existed with the same name as my new branch path name. Example:

- Remote has branch: `some_feature`
- Local has branch: `some_feature/some_subfeature`
- Local pushes branch `some_feature/some_subfeature` to Remote
- Remote has error: `(failed to lock)`

Solutions:

- Rename local branch `some_feature/some_subfeature` to `foo/some_subfeature`
- Delete remote branch `some_feature`

Answer (score 5):

What happened to me was that git was changing the capitalization of my local branch. I had an old branch named Feature/blahBlah and a new branch named feature/fooBar. The latter was renamed automatically to Feature/fooBar since git stores branches as folders and I couldn't have the same folder name with different capitalization.

To fix it, I had to **go into .git/refs/heads and rename 'Feature' to 'feature'**` so all branches would be consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible reason of problems present also on case sensitive systems is conflicting breaches names.

If remote repository contains branch `a/b` and you are trying push branch `a/b/c` same error will be reported by git (definitely this error description should be improved).

https://coderwall.com/p/qkofma/a-caution-about-git-branch-names-with-s
https://ocroquette.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/git-failed-to-lock/

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was permissions not set up correctly in the git repository. I found the solution here: [How to use group file permissions correctly on a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832346/how-to-use-group-file-permissions-correctly-on-a-git-repository)

The problem was when a new branch was created that contains a path (feature/Prizefulfilment), the folder "feature" is created in "refs/heads/" and the new folder had inherit the users group ID which prevented future users to use the same path.

To solve this you have to set the setgid to all of the directories in the git repository so that the new folder inherit its group ID, rather than group ID of the user.

```
chown -R git:git /path/to/repo
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/repo
find /path/to/repo -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had checkout a branch with all lower case lettering.  This caused an inconsistency between the remote branch and local branch names.

Remote branch was INT-4368-some-feature-details, whereas local branch was int-4368-some-feature-details.

To fix, I went into .git\refs\heads\feature and renamed the branch name to match the remote.  Then went to command line and ran

```
git checkout INT-4368-some-feature-details
```

Answer (score -1):

When you get message like this,first do pull operation from remote branch.Then do push operation.When somebody pushes files to remote server,it will shift the master branch(in case remote branch is master,it can be any name) to some other place.You need to update this in the local repository,so that origin/master in the local repository will move forward.Then add files in the local repository and commit it.Then do push operation.It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Branch name of local and remote repo not matching in terms of capitalization, you can rename your local branch using this command :-

```
git branch -m new-name
```